# Get item from database result by using entity framework linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a schedule object that is returned from the database. It contains information from a few tables. One of the tables is called ScheduleData and has four columns. It has this format:

```
Id  |  ScheduleId |  Name  |  Value
```

I need the value of the fourth column where the `Name` is `Mine` and the `ScheduleId` is `5`

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
string val = from s in schedule.ScheduleData where s.Name.Equals("Mine") && s.ScheduleId == 5 select s.Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `First` method or `FirstOrDefault` method.The query returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can't assign it to `string`.

```
string val = (from s in schedule.ScheduleData 
             where s.Name == "Mine" && s.ScheduleId == 5 
             select s.Value).First();
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me "InvalidOperationException". It says "Sequence contains no elements".

Comment: then use FirstOrDefault and check for null. the error indicates, you have no item in your database that matches with your criteria